# Using Web Service Method for Insert data to Database with Auto Increment for the Primary Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web-services, web

I'm having problem about web service method with auto increment ID.
I have a table at my Database:
tableExam

```
PK - IDExam - int - auto increment
---- ExamName - string
---- ExamGrade - int
```

then I create a web service method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void addExam(int IDExam, string ExamName, int ExamGrade)
{
    Exam e = new Exam{
    ExamName = ExamName,
    ExamGrade = ExamGrade};
}
```

then I use it to my form.
and when I click submit button, it runs:

```
sampleWS s = new sampleWS();
s.addExam(bla, bla, bla);
```

now there's an error that told me a primary key cannot be set.

> 

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tableExam' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
  at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
  at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
  at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicInsert(TrackedObject item)
  at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject item)
  at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
  at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
  at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
```

I try to change my web service like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public void addExam(string ExamName, int ExamGrade)
{
    Exam e = new Exam{
    ExamName = ExamName,
    ExamGrade = ExamGrade};
}
```

now it still have error:

> ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSourceP' could not find a non-generic method 'addExam' that has parameters: IDExam, ExamName, ExamGrade.

So, what must I do to use this WS method with auto increment PK ID?

Comment: -1. Please post code that is related to error (which is something with database constraints). Consider making console application that reproduces the problem by calling whatever method that submits do DB directly for sample to post here. Update your tags (i.e. "web" makes no sence, DB related tag missing). "Identity" is usually about "user identity", consider changing title to contain "autoincrement field".

Comment: Your post is really confusing.  AutoIncrement is a database, not a web service feature.  There is no database code.

Comment: I'm sorry to confusing You, but what I mean is how to use the method from my webservice (addExam(int IDExam, string ExamName, intExamGrade)
) but the IDExam is auto increment? because I can't use this method nor the 2nd method at above

Comment: You got typos like (intExamGrade) that should be (int ExamGrade).  Does you code compile ?

Comment: @Zachary Sorry, I'm not copy pasting it, but in my program, there's no error and I type int ExamGrade (had space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to

```
sampleWS s = new sampleWS();
s.addExam(100000000, bla, bla);
```

and it works..

thanks for Your participate...

Answer (score 0):

can you give the dal code you are using
if i look at you exception then it tells the id has identity and you are giving id a value which is wrong the id will be added  automatically. you dont have to set examid 
The error is in Query not in webmethod

Comment: I'm using DBML, so I don't write the query myself. Its generated by the dbml and I call with web service then in program, I'm using ListView with DataSourceObject